# Avoiding aggregation when selecting values from tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code which selects value from table2 when 'some string' occurs more than once in 1990

```
SELECT a.value, COUNT(*) AS test 
FROM table1 c
JOIN table2 a 
  ON c.value2 = a.value_2 
JOIN table3 o
  ON c.value3 = o.value_3 
  AND o.value4 = 1990 
WHERE c.string = 'Some string' 
GROUP BY a.value 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This works fine but I am attempting to write a query that produces a similar result without using aggregation. I just need to select values with more then 1 c.string and select those rather than counting and selecting the count as well. I thought about searching for pairs of 'some string' occurring in 1990 for a value but am unsure of how to execute this. Pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated! Struggling to find any documentation referencing this. Thank you!

Comment: How do you expect to get a count without aggregation?  I'm befuddled.

Comment: I don't really know, the task given basically said rewrite this SQL query without using aggregation

Comment: perhaps you want `window functions` the example is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a sequence number within the rows of each `table2.value`.  And use window function `FIRST_VALUE()` to get the largest row number for each `table2.value`. Use `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates:

```
select distinct value, first_value(rn) over (  order by rn desc) as count
from
(
SELECT  a.value , row_number() over (partition by a.value order by null) rn
FROM table1 c
JOIN table2 a 
  ON c.value2 = a.value_2 
JOIN table3 o
  ON c.value3 = o.value_3 
  AND o.value4 = 1990 
WHERE c.string = 'Some string'  ) t
where rn > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

To check for duplicates, you can use 'WHERE EXISTS', as a starting point. You could start by reading this:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

This will give you quite a long, cumbersome piece of code compared to using aggregation. But I expect that's the point of the task - to show how useful aggregation is.